# Can a php sub function return the main function?

Tags: php, function

For example

```
function main(){
     function sub(){
        $a = false;
        if(!$a) return main function;
     }
}
```

Something like that can be possible or there's a similar solution?

Comment: You could add a flag at the end of the subfunction and depending of its value, do somehting in the main function when you leave the sub one

Comment: Are you looking to return function **result** or function **definition**? This is an XY problem, you should explain what problem you're trying to fix by this main/sub function approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? But there must be exit.

```
function main($exit = false){
    echo 'begin main' . '<br>';

    if ($exit) {
        echo 'exit main' . '<br>';
        return;
    }

    function sub(){
        echo 'sub' . '<br>';
        return main(true);
    }

    echo 'end main' . '<br>';
}
```

if we call `sub()`, we get fatal error - `sub()` will only be defined when `main()` is called.

But if we call first `main()` and then `sub()`, sub will work:

```
main();
// begin main
// end main

sub();
// sub
// begin main
// exit main
```

Comment: That's the problem. How to stop main() when sub() call it?

Comment: To stop `main()`, it must know, who calls it. I do it with flag `$exit`. If `$exit` is false, `main()` is called from outer, we continue execution. If `$exit` is true, `main()` is called from `sub()`, so we exit.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't noticed the return within the `sub` function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not have "sub functions". What you have here are two global functions, but `sub()` will only be defined when `main()` is called..... after that, they are completely independent functions.

Answer (score 0):

main() must be called from somewhere, so you could wrap the call into a try-catch construction and exit the inner function with an Exception:

```
try{
    main();
}catch(SubException $e){
    ...
}

function main(){
    function sub(){
        $a = false;
        if(!$a) throw new SubException(...);
     }
}
```